# Convert SCSS to SCSS without Compass mixins

Tags: css, styles, sass, compass-sass

I have a SCSS file that references some Compass mixins. Now I want to include it in a project which doesn't use Compass. For that I would like to convert my SCSS with Compass mixins to a SCSS without Compass mixins. Is something like that possible?

Comment: It would be easier to *just use Compass* than to recreate all of the mixins being used.  Keep in mind that some of the things Compass offers are written in Ruby, not Sass (particularly if you're using gradients).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing myself an [Alfred](http://alfredapp.com) Workflow as file action. Now I can simply action the SCSS file with Compass mixins and I get a normal SCSS file on my Desktop. The bash code looks like this

```
export DIR=$(dirname {query})
export BASE=$(basename {query})
filename="${BASE%.*}"
dirname=${filename}$(date +%s)

compass compile --sass-dir ${DIR} --css-dir ~/Desktop/.${dirname}
sass-convert -F css -T scss ~/Desktop/.${dirname}/${filename}.css ~/Desktop/${filename}.scss
rm -r ~/Desktop/.${dirname}
```

The Alfred Workflow is available on GitHub: https://github.com/Juuro/Compass-SCSS-to-SCSS-Alfred-Workflow

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but you can take the generated css file from the first (Compass) project, and "***sass-convert***" it in the second projects. You will lose all variables and sass goodies though.

Otherwise, if it's not a very big project, you can just do a find-replace and remove the Compass mixins, or try a "***sass watch***", follow all errors and correct them by hand.

There's also "***sass --check***" that will check your syntax.